# Integer pair that satisfies 42x+55y

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I find the integer pair $(x,y)$ where $|100|\leq x,\;y\leq |200|$ that satisfies $42x+55y=1$?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_Lemma and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: then how do I find the integer pair such that x+y would be minimal?

Comment: if $x,y \geq 100$ then $42x+55y \geq 9700$. So it cannot be 1....

Comment: I forgot the absolute value sign =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Use the Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD of $42$ and $55$ then work it backwards to find the linear combination of $42$ and $55$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that for any two integers $\,a, b,$ we can express $\gcd(a, b)$ as a linear combination with $$\gcd(a, b) = ax + by, \text{where}\;\; a, b, x, y \in \mathbb Z$$

Then we can see that $\gcd(42, 55) = 42x + 55 y = 1$.

Use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to confirm that $\gcd(42, 55) = 1$ and to find $(x, y)$ satisfying $42x + 55 y = 1$, within the parameters you are working with.

Comment: Jong Sui: Does this help? I hope my edit was what you intended, given you comment below your question. The Extended Euclidean Algorithm can be fun to work with, and comes in handy.

Comment: Another nice exp and TU! :-) +1